# Flask-SQLAlchemy .like() method raises NotImplementedError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having trouble building a Flask-SQLAlchemy query with a `like()` method, which should build a query using the the SQL `LIKE` statement.

According the SQLAlchemy [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html?highlight=like#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.like) the `like` method can be called on a column like this:

```
select([sometable]).where(sometable.c.column.like("%foobar%"))
```

I have a ModelClass that subclasses the Flask-SQLAlchemy `db.Model` class. Defined like this:

```
class ModelClass(db.Model):
    # Some other columns ... 
    field1 = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('my_other_class.id'))
    rel1 = db.relationship("MyOtherClass", foreign_keys=[field1])
```

I then have a loop where I am building up filters dynamically. Outside the loop I use these filters to filter a query. The inside of my loop, slightly modified, looks like this:

```
search_term = '%{}%'.format(search_string)
my_filter = getattr(ModelClass, field_string).like(search_term)
```

This raises an error at the line with the `like` method:

```
NotImplementedError: <function like_op at 0x101c06668>
```

It raises this error for any text string. The Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError) for a `NotImplementedError` say:

> This exception is derived from RuntimeError. In user defined base
>   classes, abstract methods should raise this exception when they
>   require derived classes to override the method.

This isn't an `AttributeError`, so I think the `like` method exists, but something else is wrong and I'm not sure what.

**Update**

Now that I'm looking more closely at the model definition I think the problem might be that I'm doing this on a relationship and not a `Column` type.

I saw that `type(getattr(ModelClass, field_string))` gives:

```
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x102018090>
```

Since this is not a `Column` type I looked at the values for `field_string` and saw that one of the values being passed was actually `rel1`.

So I guess that's the "answer" but I'm still confused why calling `.like()` on `rel1` didn't raise an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've confirmed the issue is that I was trying to apply the `.like()` method to a relationship attribute instead of a column.

I changed my code to call the child model class directly as opposed to trying to go across the relationship from the parent to access the child class columns. Something like this:

```
search_term = '%{}%'.format(search_string)
my_filter = getattr(ChildModelClass, field_string).like(search_term)
```

Comment: Seems like a bummer that you can't do a .like() while using a db.relationship ... i ran into this problem myself.

Answer (score 3):

As @ACV said, calling methods such as `like()`, `is_()`, `is_not()`, etc. on relationship attributes raises `NotImplementedError`. So, to workaround this problem, I called the method directly on the real column attribute instead of the relationship. E.g. if I have the following two attributes in a Model:

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True)
user = db.relationship(
    'User', backref=db.backref('readings', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
```

I did the following query to filter the instances whose attribute `user IS NOT NULL`. (Note that I'm using `MyModel.user_id` instead of `MyModel.user` to successfully run the query):

`MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.user_id.is_not(None))`